# Can I copy an ACL from one registry key to another in PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell, acl

Based on an example in the Windows PowerShell 2.0 Administrators Pocket Consultant I'm under the impression that it should be possible to copy an ACL from one registry key to another.  Something like this

$acl = get-acl -path hkcu:\software\foo
set-acl -path hkcu:\software\bar -aclobject $acl

However I find this silent fails to work.  The command appears to complete properly however when you check the ACL on hkcu:\software\bar you find that it's ACL hasn't changed.

This pattern does work if I'm dealing with files instead of registry entries.

If I do something like this

$acl = get-acl -path hkcu:\software\bar
$rule = new-object system.security.accesscontrol.registryaccessrule `"enigma\karmac","FullControl","allow"
$acl.addaccessrule($rule)
$acl | set-acl

That does work.

So basically I'm asking if it is possible to copy registry ACL entries from one key to another, or do you need to modify the ACL of each individual registry key.

I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, running powershell 2.0 in 64bit mode.  I've also tried running the powershell session as an administrator.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I've experimented a bit more on this issue.  I've found that it is possible to copy an ACL object from one file to another.  Is it simply not possible to copy an ACL object from one registry key to another?

Answer (score 4):

Registry ACLs appear to be optimized to persist only when a change is detected in the ACL.  In short, if you want to copy ACLs from one key to another, you have to make a change (any change) to the ACL list before it will be applied to the new key:

```
$acl = get-acl -path hkcu:\software\foo
$r = $acl.GetAccessRules( $true, $true, [security.principal.ntaccount] )
$acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll( $r[0] )
$acl.AddAccessRule( $r[0] )
set-acl -path hkcu:\software\bar -aclobject $acl
```

This limitation has nothing to do with PowerShell, I've hit it in C# too.  It's something inside of the .NET framework.

Comment: Hello beefarino  I tried out your suggestion and it definitely worked.  Thank you for the info.  I noticed one other problem though.  It only works once.  After removing and readding the Access Rule I can do a set-acl -path hkcu:\software\bar -aclobject $acl.  However if I then subsequently do something like set-acl -path hkcu:\software\baz -aclobject $acl it once again doesn't apply the new ACL.  Any thoughts?  Is this possibly a bug?

Comment: Same issue - the ACL is marked as "saved" internally once the first set-item executes, so it's not applied on the second set-item unless you make another change.  In short, you have to touch the ACL object before each set-item.  non-ideal, I know.

Comment: it'd be great if you could mark this as the correct answer; i've had several people contact me about this wondering what the correct answer was....